# Looking for ideas for a 5V power supply with 12V battery backup

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking for ideas for a 5V power supply that will run from either 220V or 110V and have a battery backup. I want to use a standard 7AHr 12V sealed led acid battery.

I was looking at capacitive transformerless power supply but the unit I use pulls about 1.2Amps every now and then. Capacitive transformerless power supply can only supply low current outputs. It looks like I will have to use a transformer.

Is there a battery monitoring and charging chip, that say works with 12V. I can always use a DC/DC convertor to convert the 12V to 5V DC. I found it uses much less power that a 7805.

Comment: You are aware that a "capacitive transformerless power supply" bites when not handled with extreme care? As in bringing real and intense physical pain? Anyways, there are plenty USB-like wall wart chargers rated for 1 or 2A, why not use one of those?

Comment: Using a [6V 7Ah SLA](http://www.yuasaeurope.com/images/uploads/uk/downloads/datasheets/NP/NP7-6_UK.pdf) might be better. Do you have to use a 12V SLA?

Answer (score 4):

You have two separate problems, charging a 12 V battery from 110-220 VAC, and creating 5 V from the 12 V.

The first is easily solved with a off the shelf power supply with *universal input* and that puts out the right float charge voltage for your battery.  Most power supplies nowadays have universal input, so that part is easy.  Most lead-acid batteries are fine with being indefinitely held at the float charge voltage, which is a bit over 13 V for a "12 V" battery.  You can probably tweak up a 12 V power supply to make 13 V or so, or you may be able to get a power supply intended to charge and maintain a 12 V lead-acid battery.  Those are usually sold as *battery chargers* instead of power supplies.

As for converting 12 V to 5 V, that's a well solved problem so no need to go into detail here.  For such a voltage drop, it should be a switcher.  You should be able to find off the shelf DC-DC converter modules that can do this, or make your own with any number of buck converter chips.  There is also a drop in buck switcher replacement for the old 7805 linear regulator.  Again, there are many well trodden paths here.

Comment: Hi Olin, thank you for that. I agree about the power supply and the DC/DC converter. 1. I would have liked to use a transformerless circuit but it does not look like I can get the power I require. 2. How do I monitor the level of the battery and power it off before it discharges too much?

Comment: I'm looking for a circuit for a universal input power supply. I do not want to use off the shelf unit.

Comment: @andre: A capacitive charge pump power supply is inappropriate here.  Your power levels are too high, but more importantly, the output is not isolated from the power line.  For a lead-acid battery, it is good enough to monitor voltage to decide when to not let it discharge further.  As for a circuit for a universal input power supply, that's over your head given the kind of questions you are asking here.  That is not a beginner project.  Not only is it dangerous, but there is too much to explain.  Go buy a power supply.